# Default text in Angular select

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

By default angular uses an empty value if nothing has been selected in a `<select>`. How can I change this to a text that says `Please select one`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didnt provide any code so I can't give an example relative to your code, but try adding an option element, e.g.

```
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="item.category for item in items"
        ng-change="doSomething()">
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: To add:  Having value="" is important.  It won't work if you just omit the value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Via the `ng-selected` attribute:

```
<select>
  <option>Hello!</option>
  <option ng-selected="selected">Please select one</option>
  <option>Another option</option>
</select>
```

Check out the reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected